# aspnet 3.1 openidconnect 6.0.5 authentication, getting logged in, IsSignedIn(User) stays false?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, openid-connect, c#-6.0

This is about an application aspnetcore 3.0 with EF core
In which login security and authorization was added using openID.
The problem although users do ends up in the EF core DB, and validation does happens at openID. That after login the partial view does not recognize that the user is logged in.
So I cant make use of the username or email at other pages, kinda weird.
**loginpartial.cs   :**

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
@inject SignInManager<IdentityUser> SignInManager
@inject UserManager<IdentityUser> UserManager

<ul class="navbar-nav">
@if (SignInManager.IsSignedIn(User))
{   ... it never knows that the user is signed in
    ... despite i did get loged on by external service, and endup at the default page
```

I got the idea there is something wrong with my program.cs in which the whole configuration is givven, that i somehow have to transfer the current user towards the previous injected user manager or so.
**program.cs   :**

```
using System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Internal;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization;
using MyApplication.Data;

bool useAuthentication = true;
MyApplication.Common.AppConfig.AddOrUpdate("config:args",args);

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));

builder.Services.AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter();

builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
.AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();

builder.Services.AddControllers()
.AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
{
    options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver();
});

if (useAuthentication)
{
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
    {
     options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
     options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    })
    .AddCookie(options=>options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1))
.AddOpenIdConnect(options =>
{
    options.SignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.ClientId = builder.Configuration["OpenID:ClientID"];
    options.ClientSecret = builder.Configuration["OpenID:ClientSecret"];
    options.Authority = builder.Configuration["OpenID:Authority"];
    options.CallbackPath = builder.Configuration["OpenID:CallbackPath"];
    options.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.Code;
    options.ClaimActions.MapUniqueJsonKey("username", "username");

    options.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents
    {
        OnTokenValidated = tokencontext =>
        {
        // I could do something here with current user, 
        // though user does get into EF core thus ehm do i need this ??

            return Task.CompletedTask;
        },
        OnTicketReceived = context =>
        {
            // If authentication logic is based on users then add your logic here
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        },
        OnAuthenticationFailed = context =>
        {
            context.Response.Redirect("/Home/Error");
            context.HandleResponse(); // Suppress the exception
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        },
    };
    });
}

var app = builder.Build();

using (var scope = app.Services.CreateScope())
{
var services = scope.ServiceProvider;
var context = services.GetRequiredService<ApplicationDbContext>();
context.Database.Migrate();
}

if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
app.UseMigrationsEndPoint();
}
else
{
app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=MyApplication}/{action=Index}/{id?}").RequireAuthorization();
});

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=MyApplication}/{action=Index}/{id?}"); 

app.MapControllerRoute(name: "api", pattern: "api/{controller=Api}/{Action=Test}/{id?}/{country?}");

app.MapRazorPages();
app.Run();
```

(PS its not about older MVC5 applications, its MVC6 here)

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say without running your code locally (which I have not done).

I am, however, suspicious of how you are mapping controllers and injecting authorization to them.

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=MyApplication}/{action=Index}/{id?}").RequireAuthorization();
});

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=MyApplication}/{action=Index}/{id?}"); 

app.MapControllerRoute(name: "api", pattern: "api/{controller=Api}/{Action=Test}/{id?}/{country?}");
```

Why the difference between the two? I.e. why does the first require authorization while the second does not?

Why not use something simple like the below?

```
app.MapControllers().RequireAuthorization();
```

Comment: it was a special case where api had different security than the normal web page.